# replace break line with another equivalent line in C#

Tags: c#

I need to replace the break; line with another equivalent line without using goto, what is the possible solutions?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int Max = 100;

    for (int i = 0; i < Max; i++)
    {
       Console.Writeline(i);

        if (i == 50)
            break;
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: it was an interview question :(

Comment: Nice interview question, it will find out if you understood  for(;;)

Comment: Reject this job. After stupid interview question there will be stupid organization and tasks. And maybe stupid salary :)

Answer (score 3):

Set `i` to `Max`

```
if (i == 50)
      i = Max;
```

This will stop the loop from running. It's not exactly same as `break`.Since it will execute the code after the `if` statement, you may need to use `continue` to skip it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you break at 50, which is then basically the maximum value that could be possibly achieved (using only the code you posted), why don't you simply set `Max` to 51 instead of 100? The outcome would be the same!

Answer (score 1):

I really love this stupid interview question: Is this valid ?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int Max = 100;

    for (int i = 0; i < Max; i++)
    {

       if(i >= 51)
          continue;

        Console.Writeline(i);

    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: No, actually, this doesn't work. This will print only `50` and still run untill `Max`.

Comment: Yep I saw it :) Now it is fixed

Comment: Now it works, but it is bad: It will use the CPU to cycle through i++ 50 times - uselessly (does this word exist?)

Comment: @DrKoch I know and ... ;) The cost of this is ~ 0. Whatever the question was fun :)

Answer (score 1):

```
i = Max;
```

Explanation: It is perfectly legal to manipulate the loop variable (i) inside a for loop.
At the end of the loop the for-chack is executed (i < Max) if it evaluates to false the loop terminates

In fact these two are equivalent:

```
for(int i=0; i < 3; i++)
{
    DoSomething(i);
}
```

Will transformed by the compiler to **exactly**:

```
  i=0;
start:
  if(i<3)
  {
    DoSomething(i);
    i++;
    goto start;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you dont have to keep the 'if' statement :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int Max = 100;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 50; i++) // stop when i > 50 
    {
       Console.WriteLine(i);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

or

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int Max = 50;

    for (int i = 0; i <= Max; i++)  // stop when i > Max
    {
       Console.WriteLine(i);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

[Demo DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vKJTC2)

Comment: If this was asked to me on interview I was going to write this :)I'm really annoyed from questions like this ! :) +1 ;)

Comment: If they chose to add it, they have a reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (i == 50)
   return;
```

This should do the trick too